# Redis: What exactly are all those db instances are for?

Tags: redis

I am new to redis and when I fired it up, it initially had 16 db instances.

Is there a special reason why there are exactly 16 dbs? I am wondering whether they are there for some kind of specific purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a default configuration. The default database is #0. Others will remain unused until you [SELECT](http://redis.io/commands/select) them.
You can change the number of DBs of a Redis server by modifying the value of the entry `databases` in the config file `redis.conf`.